# How can I use the same function for different type parameters which have the same member?

Tags: c#

BHere is the sample code, I've defined two classes. How can I use the `Output` function to output the member which has the same name in two different classes?

```
class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public A(string name, int age, string email)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Email = email;
    }
}

class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public B(string name, int age, string location)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Location = location;
    }
}

void Output(object obj)
{
    // How can I convert the object 'obj' to class A or class B
    // in order to output its 'Name' and 'Age'
    Console.WriteLine((A)obj.Name); // If I pass a class B in pararmeter, output error.
}
```

Comment: Are `A` and `B` related in any way other than having some similar members? That is, is it conceivable for them to inherit from a shared parent type?

Comment: @Oded - I think that would be the way too. Using `dynamic` here is never best practice.

Comment: Another option is to overload `Output` for `A` and `B` and have a private function that can be used by the overloads after extracting the data from each.

Comment: @Oded - That is funny because I just wrote that as an answer right before you made that comment. I like your style :P

Comment: Why is the `Name` property private? How would it work then (except with reflection)? The instance constructor of `B` is called `A` (illegal).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - That looks like a copy paste error to me.

Comment: @TravisJ why not use `dynamic` here? If I don't want to add a new interface for these class?

Comment: @Eddie: Using `dynamic` will mean that you have to catch errors at runtime rather than them being caught at compile time. You will have traded compile-time certainty for runtime uncertainty. If you use `dynamic` you must handle the case where the `Name` property is missing, or not a string, or not even a property (it could be a method or an event, for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to either:

1. Use Reflection to get the property (and throw if it isn't there)
2. Have a common interface, such as `INamed` that has a string `Name` property, that each of the two classes implement
3. Declare a local variable as `dynamic` and use it to access the `Name` property (but in effect this is the same as #1, because the dynamic dispatch will merely use Reflection to get the `Name` property).

Comment: Thank you. Any efficiency problems in #3?

Comment: @Eddie using reflection is typically slower than direct property calls, but it will certainly work. In the end, you'd have to actually measure the performance of the application to see if this is the hot spot. Chances are, things like database access and network calls will significantly outweigh a little bit of reflection. But you'd have to measure to be certain.

Answer (score 5):

You can take advantage of [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx) to bypass the compiler, it checks the type at runtime so you don't need to cast:

```
void Output(dynamic obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Name); 
}
```

Comment: How much of performance penalty you get because of runtime type check?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Just one of approaches, but don't be fall into premature optimization. In big application, this point of performance for dynamic is trivial

Answer (score 5):

You should declare an interface which will describe the common part of both classes:

```
interface I
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then implement it in both `A` and `B` :

```
class A : I
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public A(string name, int age, string email)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Email = email;
    }
}

class B : I
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public B(string name, int age, string location)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Location = location;
    }
}
```

And change your method to get `I` as parameter:

```
void Output(I obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Name); 
}
```

Comment: It is also possible to make `Name` etc. `get`-only inside the interface `I`. In that case `A` and `B` are allowed to make the `set`ter `private` which is desirable in some cases (type could be made immutable for example).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Good point! But my answer was more like just a way he could go, so I'll leave it as it is now.

Comment: This is what I would do. Using `dynamic` to solve it is the wrong approach IMHO. I note that none of the answers that suggest `dynamic` even mention, let alone address what to do when using `dynamic` throws exceptions due to `Name` being missing, or being the wrong type, or being a method rather than a property and so on. Trading compile-time correctness for potential run-time errors is just bad.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dynamic`, reflection, or inheritance. Or you could just duplicate the method and take advantage of method overloading

```
void Output(A obj)
{
 // in order to output its 'Name' and 'Age'
 Console.WriteLine(obj.Age);
 Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
}

void Output(B obj)
{
 // in order to output its 'Name' and 'Age'
 Console.WriteLine(obj.Age);
 Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a common interface for both classes, so the compiler knows that both classes can dliver certain features (Name and age in your case):

```
    interface IHasNameAndAge
    {
        string Name { get; }
        int Age { get; }
    }

    class A : IHasNameAndAge
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        string Email { get; set; }

        public A(string name, int age, string email)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
            Email = email;
        }
    }

    class B : IHasNameAndAge
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        string Location { get; set; }

        public A(string name, int age, string location)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
            Location = location;
        }
    }

    void Output(IHasNameAndAge obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Name + " is " + obj.Age);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case - B does not inheret from A, so you cannot cast B to A.

Change B to inherit from A, like

```
class B : A
{
...
}
```

Also - consider what are you trying to accomplish in your A() method of B class.
And - if you inherited, you probably need not same members to be declared twice.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
if ( obj.GetType() == typeof( A ) )
{
    Console.WriteLine(((A)obj).Name);
}
else if ( obj.GetType() == typeof( B ) )
{
    Console.WriteLine(((B)obj).Name);
}
```

Comment: It is the last way to consider. I never suggest this.

Comment: Why not `if (obj is A)` and so on?